# Changing units in Fourier filtering

Tags: physical-units

I'm applying a radial low-pass filter on a $H{\times}W$ pixel 2D image $I$ where $H \neq W$. To implement this filter, I apply 2D DFT to $I$ to produce $I'$, the $H{\times}W$ frequency domain representation of $I$. I apply an element-wise multiplication $I' \odot M$ with a filter matrix $M \in \{0, 1\}^{H{\times}W}$. Let $u \in \{0, H-1\}, v \in \{0, W-1\}$ be indices in $M$. $u$ represents cycles/entire height of image, while $v$ represents cycles/entire width of image. An ideal low-pass filter with radius $R_{img}$ is given by
$$\sqrt{u^2 + v^2} < R_{img},$$
whose units are in cycles/image. I want to change the units of the filter parameter $R_{img}$ from cycles/image to cycles/mm, given that $\gamma$ = mm/pixel.

Here is what I have so far, please let me know if this is correct. Since the filter radius can't exceed $\min(H, W)$, let $f_s = \min(H, W)$ denote the sampling frequency of the image across both dimensions in terms of cycles/image, and $u, v$ denote row and column indices of the $H{\times}W$ representation of the image in frequency domain after applying shifted 2D DFT. We then have

$$\sqrt{u^2 + v^2} < R_{img}\\
\frac{1}{f_s \gamma} \sqrt{u^2 + v^2} < \frac{R_{img}}{f_s \gamma}\\
\sqrt{\left(\frac{u}{f_s \gamma}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{v}{f_s \gamma}\right)^2} < \frac{R_{img}}{f_s \gamma},$$

where the units have changed from cycles/image to cycles/mm. In other words,
$$R_{mm} = \frac{R_{img}}{f_s \gamma}.$$

Comment: @Fat32 I've reposted the question, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi. There are problems in your question. $f_s$ is sampling frequency in *samples per meter* (or *samples per mm*) but $H$ and $W$ are image dimensions in *samples* (or *pixels*). Then how do you set $f_s = \min(H,W)$

Comment: Also please pay extreme attention to clearly  distinguish between *spatial domain*, *frequency domain*, *continuous-time* and *discrete-time* variables and indices. A careless mixture is the worst thing in the world to deal with.

Comment: @Fat32 I'll edit my question to make these details explicit.

Comment: @Fat32 The units of $f_s$ are supposed to be cycles per entire height/length of image. I wanted to use $u/H \gamma$ and $v / W \gamma$ to represent cycles/pixel, but doing so with $H \neq W$ is problematic, so I'm assuming that the circular mask is completely enclosed by a $f_s{\times}f_s$ square centered at the origin, where $f_s = min(H, W)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** your conclusion seems ok.

Concept of **units** make sense only in the world of **physics**. Mathematical objects such as DFT trasforms do not have any kind of units but just their values, quasi exceptions being the planar angle meausure of *radian* and volumetric angle mesaure of the *steradian*. However, when a variable represents a physical quantity (as almost always is the case) then it's customary to associate units with those mathematical variables as well.

Let's do a 1D analysis of those units, from which the 2D version follows straightforwardly. Discrete-time variables are indexed sequences such as $x[n]$ or $X[k]$ which may represent samples of a continuous-time signal $x(t)$ and the DFT of $x[n]$ respectively.

We can assume that a sequence $x[n]$ bears a **unit** which is the unit of the associated physical variable $x(t)$ from which $x[n]$ was sampled. So if $x(t)$ was a voltage in units of Volt,   then the unit of $x[n]$ will be Volt too.

The index $n$ does not have any units which can be seen by the following uniform sampling relation :

$$ t_n = n T_s $$

where $t_n$ is the sampling time with a unit of second (s), and $T_s$ is the sampling period with a unit of second (s) too; hence the index number $n$ is **unitless**. However, some like to call $n$ with a unit of **samples**. Yet this is not only unnecessary but also as meaningless as associating a unit with room numbers in a hotel. Nevertheless it's customary to do so and I do also use it.

The 1D-DFT $X[k]$ associated with a given sequence $x[n]$ is defined as follows:

$$ X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{ j \frac{2\pi}{N} k n} $$

The *complex exponential* function (as well as other trigonometric functions such as *sine*, *cosine*, *tangent*) produce unitless outputs as pure numbers. The trigonometric functions expects **angles** in units of **radians** as their input arguments.

Therefore, the unit of the DFT $X[k]$ will be that of the sequence $x[n]$.

The unit of the DFT frequency bin index $k$ is found from the unit of the complex exponential argument :

$$ \frac{2 \pi }{N} k n = \theta $$

In this expression, the sample index $n$ and the total sample count $N$ (or *frame length* as some would like to call) have no units (or they both have the unit of *samples*, but it will cancel neverthelesss) and the angles $\theta$ and $2\pi$ have the unit of *radians* hence the DFT frequency index $k$ is **unitless** too.

How about calling the frequency variable $k$ as *cycles per frame length* ? Ok, it is also preferred and some may find it informative to call $k$ as the number of cycles a sine wave fits into the given frame length of analysis.

With the same reasoning, a 2D intensity image sample sequence $f[n,m]$ will have units of intensity and the spatial index variables $m,n$ are either unitless or given a samples unit. And for the 2D-DFT $X[u,v]$, the frequency index variables $u,v$ are **unitless**. Nevertheless, again some prefer calling them in the units of *cycles per image frame length* and you can also do it.

Now coming to the units of the expression

$$ \sqrt{ u^2 + v^2 } < R ,$$

the variable $R$ is either unitless as explained above or can be associated with the unit of *cycles per frame length* as some would prefer. From your expanded questions, it became clear that you wanted to change the **scale** of this actually unitless parameter from *cycles per frame length* to *cycles per mm*.

Now, to find out the continuous-space frequency in *cycles per meter* associated with a given DFT frequency bin index $u$ or $v$ , you would actually perform the following conversion :

$$ f_u =  \frac{u}{H} F_s $$

where $u$ is the unitless DFT frequency bin index count, $H$ is the number of samples (frame length in samples or image height in your example) and $F_s$ is the sampling frequency in cycles per meter (I assume). In your project you set $f_s = H$ (assuming $H = \min(H,W)$) and you give a **pixel-size** parameter of $\gamma$ in *mm/pixel* units. Then this $\gamma$ is the inverse of sampling frequency $F_s$ in *samples per mm*. And the above formula becomes :

$$ f_u =  \frac{u}{f_s} F_s = \frac{u}{f_s} \frac{1}{\gamma} = \frac{u}{f_s \gamma} $$

Finally since the ideal circular lowpass filter bandwidth radius parameter $R$ is a same kind of variable with DFT frqeuency bin index variable $u$ or $v$, therefore its conversion from *cycles per frame length* to **cycles per mm** will be done using the same formula:

$$ r =  \frac{R}{f_s} F_s = \frac{R}{f_s} \frac{1}{\gamma} = \frac{R}{f_s \gamma} $$

where $r$ has the units of *cycles per mm*.

Comment: Thank you for the formalism surrounding units. Our conversion relies on the frame length $f_s$ being the same across the horizontal and vertical axes of the image, even when $H \neq W$. I justified this by saying that when considering a circular mask that is completely enclosed by a rectangle, we only need to consider the square with sides equal to $\min(H, W)$ at the center of the rectangle. Is this rationalization ok, or is there a better way of expressing it?